# php function preg_replace regex not working, a syntax question

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, pcre

im trying to remove unnessary comments with preg-replace in controlled script situations, but my regex is incorrect. Anyone any ideas whats wrong with my regex? (i have Apache/2.0.54 & PHP/5.2.9

## BEFORE:

```
// Bla Bli Blue Blow Bell Billy Bow Bye
script var etc ();    // cangaroo cognac codified cilly celine cocktail couplet
script http://blaa.org    // you get the idea!
```

## AFTER:

```
script var etc ();
script http://blaa.org
```

## PROBLEM: what regex to use?

```
# when comment starts on a new line, delete this entire line
# find [a new line] [//] [space or no space] [comment]
$buffer = preg_replace('??', '??', $buffer);

# when comment is halfway in script (    //  comment)
# find [not beginning of a line] [1 TAB] [//] [1 space again] [comment]
$buffer = preg_replace('??', '??', $buffer);
```

Any and All suggestions will be valued +1 by me, cuase im so darn close to solve this riddle!

Comment: Have you considered using a proper tokenizer instead of a regex?  You will be able to throw out only the comment tokens.

Comment: What about multi-line comments? Especially nested multi-line comments? That's hideously non-trivial for regex, but trivial for a tokenizer /* this is a /* nested comment */

Comment: Writing comments consistently, means there is no room for such a strange thing Marc B, a comment within a commment. Nevertheless  ironic that such a lecture on consistency comes from the mouth of a very incapable programmer, namely myself hahah!

Comment: Thanks CDHowie, what is a tokenizer? can you give an example how to use that? I have a general question about this regex thing: does it belong to PHP, to Apache or somethin else? and is a Tokenizer same as Regex but with only different syntax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this regex:

```
/(?<!http:)\/\/[^\r\n]*/
```

Be cautious though, consider strings like:

```
<!-- 
// not a comment -->
```

or

```
/* 
// not a comment */
```

and

```
var s = "also // not // a // comment";
```

And you might want to work around `https://...` and `ftp://...` etc.

Comment: # BEAUTIFULL!!!! lacking those strange situations with comments in a comment gives space for even cleaner code: your regex worked first time out of the box! wish you a great weekend Bart!

Comment: @Sam, you're welcome. Weekend? That will take a few more days, but thanks and you have a nice day too! :)